# AngularJS : Getting JSON Parse Error when trying to access Hipchat REST API

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, hipchat

Am trying to access Hipchat REST APIs from AngularJS. Am getting 200 response code. 
This is the code snippet:

$.ajax({

type: 'GET',

url: "http://api.hipchat.com/v1/users/list?format=json&auth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",

dataCharset: 'jsonp',

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

dataType: "jsonp",

success: function(data, status) {

alert(status);

},

error: function(data,status) {

alert(status);

}

});

In Firefox, am getting the response as you see in the screenshot below, but getting parse error.

[image]

In Chrome, am not getting any response, but only parse error, as you can see below.

[image]

Can someone please help?

Comment: copy your response json into http://jsonlint.com/ and tell where it breaks

Comment: In AngularJS, you should use $http service, instead of jQuery $.ajax, for both json and jsonp...